# Error with detecting Keypresses in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, traceback

I have recently been creating a cops and robbers game in pygame. All my code was working until I tried to add control of the cop. Here is what I am using for it:

```
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
            coprect[0] -= 5
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
            coprect[0] += 5
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
            coprect[1] -= 5
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
            coprect[1] += 5
```

Earlier in the code I have:

```
pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 2)
```

So that the keypresses are repeated.

The error I get is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users*username*\Documents\Programming\colour_flasher.py", line 22, in 
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
NameError: name 'K_LEFT' is not defined

Any help available?
Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try:

`pygame.K_LEFT`

it should work

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html

Comment: get_pressed is for when you want to "do action while this key being held down". Which I use For WASD. But other keys that use "on press" I use event handling. Then I don't have to mess with keys auto-repeating.